# EnterpriseLibrary.Data.NetCore - Parameter discovery is not supported for connections using GenericDatabase

Tags: asp.net-core, enterprise-library

Using enterprise library for .Net Core for data access 
EnterpriseLibrary.Data.NetCore 6.0.1313 with ASP.NET MVC Core 2.2 web app with SQL Server 2016 and calling ExecuteSprocAccessor is not working with parameter values.

I am creating ASP.NET MVC Core 2.2 web app with enterprise library for .Net Core for data access. 
EnterpriseLibrary.Data.NetCore 6.0.1313. I want to call ExecuteSprocAccessor without defining paramter map and just passing a value. I have writtern one stored procedure to call with one parameter and passing only one paratmer value in ExecuteSprocAccessor like this

sqlDatabase.ExecuteSprocAccessor("[app].[User_SelectByUserName]", "johnK").FirstOrDefault();

and stored procedute is

ALTER PROC [app].[User_SelectByUserName] 
 @UserName NVARCHAR(100)

AS

BEGIN

SELECT FROM [app].[User]

END

But I am getting following error.

{System.NotSupportedException: Parameter discovery is not supported for connections using GenericDatabase. You must specify the parameters explicitly, or configure the connection to use a type deriving from Database that supports parameter discovery.
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql.SqlDatabase.DeriveParameters(DbCommand discoveryCommand)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.DiscoverParameters(DbCommand command)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.ParameterCache.SetParameters(DbCommand command, Database database)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.AssignParameters(DbCommand command, Object[] parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.SprocAccessor`1.Execute(Object[] parameterValues)

Comment: I have the same problem! Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in a new version (6.1.10-rc). I know it's a pre-release version but looks like the package is no longer maintained